# Filter with input search not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a plunker example with this plugin
[Angular Multi Level Menu](https://github.com/wuxiaoying/angular-multilevelpushmenu/blob/master/demo/demo.js)

**Index.html**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search">
<wxy-push-menu menu="menu" options="options"></wxy-push-menu>
```

**SubMenu.html**

```
<div ng-show="visible" ng-class="{visible: visible, multilevelpushmenu_inactive: inactive && !collapsed}" class="levelHolderClass">
<h2><i class="floatRight cursorPointer" ng-class="menu.icon" ng-click="openMenu($event, menu)"></i>{{menu.title}}</h2>
<div ng-show="level != 0 && !inactive" ng-class="options.backItemClass">
    <a href="#" ng-click="goBack($event, menu)">
        <i class="floatRight" ng-class="options.backItemIcon"></i><span ng-bind="options.backText"></span>
    </a>
</div>
<ul ng-class="{invisible: inactive}">
    <li ng-repeat="item in menu.items | filter: search">
        <a ng-href="{{item.link}}" ng-click="onSubmenuClicked(item, $event)">
            <i ng-if="item.menu" class="floatLeft iconSpacing" ng-class="options.groupIcon"></i>
            <i class="floatRight" ng-class="item.icon"></i>{{item.name}}
        </a>
        <div ng-if="item.menu">
            <recursive><wxy-submenu menu="item.menu" level="childrenLevel" visible="item.visible"></wxy-submenu></recursive>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Any idea why the filter not work?

[Plunker Code](https://plnkr.co/edit/VsdUdrPQryYBr4nrIKoA?p=preview)

Comment: You've issues with your directive that needs investigation, if you don't use `wxy-submenu` works fine. So check your directive!

Comment: That directive belong to the plugin

Comment: Than maybe it doesn't support searching!